# Webmaster tools do not show a website as verified using Site Verification API

Tags: google-oauth, google-search-console, google-site-verification-api

Why Google webmaster tool doesn't show the verified site on the webmaster tool? I am getting status code 200 when using both OAuth 2 playground and my program.  But when check on https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ I cannot see the verified site.

This is the response I am getting from Google:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 220
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Etag: "00deUEyKiunbfrZpRY_GOwanRBXo/rPzr3x8uGF7cZ_o8tWZ9Z9Yp87RwQU"
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2013 09:38:26 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

{"id":"http%3A%2F%2Fsample.net%2F","site":{"type":"SITE","identifier":"http://sample.net/"},"owners":["sample@gmail.com"]}
```

Can anyone suggest the reason behind this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out why?

Comment: I have used different Google account. If you use same account again and again you will face this issue.